# Change the location of the text in the flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm creating my own chat on flutter and I need the time of the last message to be in the upper right corner from the person who wrote [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7inYt.png)! But I do not know how to do it, I will be grateful if you help!

```
child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60),
                          child: Image.asset("images/churka.jpg", height: 60,
                            width: 60,
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,)),
                      SizedBox(width: 10.0,),
                      Column(
                        // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(height: 10,),
                          Row(

                            children: [
                              Text('Человек', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Text('Как дела',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(
                                87, 87, 87, 1.0),
                                fontSize: 16,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),),
                        ],

                      ),
                      Text('11:11', style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(
                          87, 87, 87, 1.0),
                          fontSize: 16,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

I tried to put `mainAxisAlignment` in different ways, but then the position of the name and the last message changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, look at the chat item architecture which is composed of set of `Rows` and `Coulmns`.

```
Row(

      children: [
        CircleAvatar(
          radius: 25,
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 20,
        ),
        Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Row(

              children: [
                Text('Crystoph Waltz'),
                SizedBox(width: 20,),
                Text('12:00 PM')
              ],
            ),
            Text('The last Message!'),
          ],
        ),
      ],

    ),
```

take care, the above texts are static, when you use dynamic text that may change in length you must impose constraints to avoid annoying overflow.

[image: it's a list view of chat items]

Comment: @Faer Bot see the updates.